# Recive [Errno 111] Connection refused on load test for TCP Server

Tags: rust, load-testing, tcpclient, locust, connection-refused

I'm trying to set up a job make a load test on a TCP server. The idea is for each 'client' to connect to the server, send a message and close the connection (without waiting for a response).

Doing this for 1 client works fine, when I scale using Locust, from 1000 clients, I start to receive `[Errno 111] Connection refused`, following the pattern in the graph below.

[image]

For those who want to replicate, here is the rust TCP server, for testing:

```rust
use chrono::Local;
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

use std::error::Error;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:5102".to_string();

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await?;
    let now = Local::now();
    println!("{} -> Server started ...", now.format("%Y-%m-%d %T"));
    println!("Listening on: {}", addr);

    loop {
        let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];

            loop {
                let n = socket
                    .read(&mut buf)
                    .await
                    .expect("failed to read data from socket");

                if n == 0 {
                    return;
                }

                let now = Local::now();
                print!("{} -> ", now.format("%Y-%m-%d %T"));
                for c in buf[0..n].iter() {
                    print!("{}", format!("{:X}", c));
                }
                println!("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The cargo file:

```ini
[package]
name = "tcp_server_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
chrono = "0.4.27"
```

The Locust Script:

```py
import time
import socket
from locust import User, task, between, events

ENV = "host.docker.internal:5102"

def success(rq_type, name, r_size, r_time):
    events.request.fire(
            request_type=rq_type,
            name=name,
            response_time=r_time,
            response_length=r_size,
            exception=None,
    )

def failure(rq_type, name, r_size, r_time, exception):
    events.request.fire(
            request_type=rq_type,
            name=name,
            response_time=r_time,
            response_length=r_size,
            exception=exception
    )

class TCP_locust():
    request_type = "TCP"
    def send_message(self) -> None:
        """Locust: Envia apenas um login"""
        name = "Send Message"
        start_time = time.time()
        sock = socket.socket()
        err = ""
        r_size = 0
        [host, port] = ENV.split(":")

        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect((host, int(port)))
        except socket.error as exc:
            err = f"Create, con: {exc}"

        if err == "":
            try:
                sock.sendall(b"test")
            except socket.error as exc:
                err = f"Send: {exc}"

        sock.close()
        response_time = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000

        if not err:
            success(self.request_type, name, r_size, response_time)
        else:
            failure(self.request_type, name, r_size, response_time, err)

class TCPClient(User):
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super().__init__(environment)
        self.client = TCP_locust()

class TCP_User(TCPClient):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task
    def micodus_send_position(self):
        self.client.send_message()
```

A docker compose file to upload Locust with 10 workers (put in the same folder of Locust Script):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
      - "5557:5557"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master --users 3000 --spawn-rate 100 --host "host.docker.internal:5102"

  worker:
    image: locustio/locust
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host host.docker.internal
    network_mode: "host"
```

Use the follow command do start

```bash
docker compose up -d --build --scale worker=10
```

I've already tested it on other TCP servers, made in C#, Rust and Python, and I ended up having the same behavior.

Initially the tests were done with Python's own threads, without using Locust, and the same thing happened. I decided to switch to Locust to collect information and have better control over the tests.

PS: This server and script are not the ones I use in the real test, I just isolated the problem to better analyze it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way to load test a TCP server, but I need to test how at least +10k 'clients' have this behavior, connect, send a message and close the connection. (I can't change the form of communication, since it's embedded boards)

Comment: What listen backlog are you using here? You'll need to increase it significantly for higher loads.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the default, 128. I changed it to 50k and still [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: It might be related to the network stack itself, not your code per-se, so it's worth testing this on some other known-good implementation, server of your choice, so see how it behaves.

Comment: I made a few more attempts, it seems to be a limit problem on the computer. Leaving below 130 requests per second (rps) in these tests, there is no problem with the connection. I did a test where I left it on my machine at 120 rps and on another machine too, with the same script, and there were no connection problems and the server received all the messages.

Comment: There's a lot that can go wrong here, so another theory is you're running out of TCP ports to use. When benchmarking very high connection loads you often need to break out from just, say, 127.0.0.1 and make connections to the entire 127.x.x.x range to ensure you're not exhausting the ports. Each TCP connection is uniqued by source_ip:source_port:dest_ip:dest_port, and given that source_ip, dest_ip, and dest_port are all constant in normal testing, that limits how many concurrent connections you can have.

Comment: Hi, it took me a while to be able to test this option (I had other demands). Running on a local host and using 127.xxx.xxx.xxx works for me to test with more connections, however my real test is on a remote server, so I have no way to change the IP. Do you have any ideas or have you done this type of test? Making a large load of connections on a server?

Comment: It depends what kind of network you're on. If it's local you can grab more IPs for your local machine and bind them as aliases. If it's via NAT you may be able to do the same, but at the risk of overloading your NAT firewall if it can't handle the number of connections required. At that point you may need to spin up a small herd of cloud servers to spread out the load.